# "Required" validation doesn't work in <select> with default value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-validation

I have a required `<select>` field:

```
<select name="service_id" class="Sitedropdown" style="width: 220px;" 
        ng-model="ServiceID" 
        ng-options="service.ServiceID as service.ServiceName for service in services"
        required> 
  <option value="">Select Service</option> 
</select>
```

When it is empty, the form should display a "Select service" error message. Here's a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xmycAAkWZI5VOogi1MyQ).

It works fine when you intentionally selects the empty option. But when you reload the page, the `service_id` is empty by default and there is no validation. How to make AngularJS validate the default value?

Comment: You're right. I'll post the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code:

`ng-show="myForm.service_id.$dirty && myForm.service_id.$invalid`"

This means - if value is dirty (was changed) and is invalid. Remove first and you'll get what you want.

Comment: @enkryptor I've the same issue could you help me?

Comment: @WarisSarwar all I need to do is to remove the `myForm.service_id.$dirty` clause

Answer (score 1):

Validation checks are only run after the value bound to `ng-model` is changed at least once, **or** when the user attempts to submit the form. If that was not the case, all the required fields of a form would be shown with error right after page loading, which would be a pretty undesirable behavior.

That's why you only see the error when selecting something else and then changing it back to the empty value.

Comment: Wrong. Validation runs on page load. http://plnkr.co/edit/ZCxv9cAlXxvPomOY6oy0?p=preview.  But yes, errors usually are not displayed on page load.